# getting Error: 20,with stat_code:3 while Setting up agora.io Recording server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, agora.io

I'm trying to set up a recording for audio on ubuntu. I downloaded http://download.agora.io/sdk/release/Agora_Recording_SDK_for_Linux_v2_2_3_FULL.tar.gz file copied the bin & include files to the server's bin & include. Changed the directory to cd PATH-TO-PROJECT/samples/cpp and ran the "make" command. It successfully generated the "recorder_local" file. when i'm trying to run it with the format

```
./recorder_local --appId APPID --uid 0 --channel mychannel --appliteDir PATH-TO-PROJECT/bin/AgoraCoreService
```

as mentioned here https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Recording/tree/master/Agora-LinuxServer-Recording. I keep getting the error

> Recording directory is ./20181127/mychannel_131813/
>   Error: 20,with stat_code:3
>   Stopped".

PS: I'm trying to record an audio stream

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

From your error I can see that the error is internal, the arguments are valid. The error was generated by creating a process.

Since you didn't posted the code that you have changed, try to add some breakpoints or cerr/couts in your code. I would look at `createChannel`.

Also, if you didn't copied the erorr right (I see that you added a `".` at the end) and the error code is 2 not 20 then your error is in your arguments that you pass.